# Problem while selecting too many items in multilist with search

Tags: sitecore-client, fieldtype

I have a multilist with search field and on the left hand side there are 1100 items which we can select. But when I select more than 130-140 items, the left hand side field gets emptied and I am not able to select more items to move to the right side. I changed the setting `Query.MaxItems` to a value of 10000 in the sitecore.config file but it is still not working.

I am using Solr 7.2.1 and Sitecore 9.1 initial release

Comment: Anything in log or Search.log?

Comment: some times i get the remote server returned an error uri too long 414 .

Comment: Try to set `maxRequestLength` in Sitecore `web.config` file to 10x what is now and see if that helps: `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="5120000"`

Comment: `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" maxRequestLength="512000" executionTimeout="600" enableKernelOutputCache="false" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" requestValidationMode="4.0" enableVersionHeader="false" requestValidationType="Sitecore.Web.RequestValidators.SitecoreBackendRequestValidator, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  `

Comment: And look at this question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/solr-query-length-limit

Comment: Tried increasing the `maxRequestLength` , didn`t get results . and for the postsolr is tried this one [link](https://kylekingsbury.com/configuring-sitecores-solrprovider-to-use-solrpostconnection/)

Comment: I see the same, URI Too Long. in the log, not only for Sitecore 9.1 but also for 9.0. easy to reproduce. Can you report this to Sitecore support and let us know what they answer?   ...otherwise a multilist with more than 100 values, perhaps it is not entirely meant for that and you can better go for a different solution.